# Dropdown Option value not persisted to the database

Tags: java, spring

In my form I have a dropdown like the following :

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label"> Level</label> <select class="form-control  input-lg" id="activityLevel" name="activityLevel">
         <option value="none"> &nbsp; </option>
         <option value="1"> First</option>
         <option value="2"> Second</option>
         <option value="3">Third</option>
         <option value="4">Fourth</option>

       </select>
 </div>
```

I have two classes :
The Levels class that has these fields :

```
@Entity
public class ActivityLevel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "activitylevel_id")
private Long id;

@Lob
@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String activityLevel;

private Double score;
//getters and setters
```

And the Survey class where one of the fields is :

```
private String name;
private String lastName;
@OneToOne
@JsonManagedReference
@JoinColumn(name = "activitylevel_id")
private ActivityLevel activityLevel;
```

Extending JpaRepository for this Survey class, I use the save(survey) to save the object.
Every other field gets persisted to the database except the value of the Option.

The reason I'm doing this is so that if option value 1 is selected and I have 1 for that field..that I will need to access the Score of the ActivityLevel where id=1.  If i change the field to being private String activityLevel;without foreign key or one to one mapping then the value gets saved.

Maybe there's a better way to do this ?
Because what I want is to have some values and score saved on the database beforehand for the ActivityLevel table.

Answer (score 0):

First, what you're missing is `(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` on your `@OneToOne`.

Second, I'm not sure that you want it to be `@OneToOne` anyway, since it will create unique option for each object. Probably `@OneToMany` would suit you better here.

Comment: Thanks you.I did change the relationship `@ManyToOne`
                                        `@JsonBackReference`
                                      `@JoinColumn(name = "activitylevel_id")`
                                      `private ActivityLevel activityLevel;`

But the activityLevel field on the Survey Table in the database is still null :|

Comment: Did you specify `(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` as I mentioned, since that's what should solve your problem, no the other stuff.

Comment: Yes I did. Still the same. 
It's interesting cuz I use the same in the same form to add another field that's foreign key..And it works for that one